# How to search within a specific range of positions on a line

Tags: command-line, text-processing, grep

I have a text file that has 60 character positions. I want to be able to search for a value/word entered by the user in positions 05-12. How do I go about doing this without using awk, pearl, etc?

For example the text file is

```
commA6314   ifosfamide               30     12 

home5341209 urokinase    6314               37
```

And if someone inputs `6314`, then it would output the line

```
commA6314   ifosfamide               30     12
```

I was thinking of using `grep`, but not too sure. Any help?

Comment: why "without using awk"? it's an obvious choice for data that's structured into fields such as this

Comment: That's the challenge my prof gave us, but I have no clue going about this other than using awk

Comment: Also I'm not clear what you mean by "columns" in this context: your example seems to show a match in the *first* (whitespace delimited) column - not between columns 05-12. Or are you referring to character positions?

Comment: character positions, sorry

Comment: I think it might be fairly easy with grep, at least my quick test seemed to work fine. (it is on purpose I'm not yet saying how I did it.)

Comment: OK - so you're looking for a 4-character string that starts at least 4 characters after the beginning of a line, and no more than (12-4) characters after the beginning of the line. Is that enough to get you started?

Comment: `bash` alone can do it, no need for external tools.  See my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
grep -E "^.{4}.?.?.?.?.?.?.?$pattern"
```

where `$pattern` is the user input, I mean in something like

```
$ echo "enter a pattern: "; read pattern; grep -E "^.{4}.?.?.?.?.?.?.?$pattern" file
enter a pattern: 
6314
commA6314   ifosfamide               30     12
```

`^.{4}.?.?.?.?.?.?.?` that's the first 4 characters locked, then the next 7 characters are optional, meaning if the pattern is only one character and it's in the 12th position, it would be found, and if it's 7 characters and starts from the 5th position, it would still be found.

- `^` start of line
- `.` any character
- `{4}` four of the preceding character
- `?` zero or one of the preceding character

Answer (score 1):

Bash allows extracting sub-strings of specific variable. All you have to do is read file line by line within `while IFS= read -r` structure:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line;
do
    if [[ ${line:5:12} =~ "$1" ]];
    then
        echo "$line"
    fi
done < "$2"
```

Note the syntax: in `${var:5:12}`  5 is starting position and 12 is offset, so in this case it searches from char position 5 till 17. If you need to calculate off-set based on user's input, you can use bash arithmetic to determine off-set like `end=$((12-5))` and use that variable within substring expression like `${var:5:$end}`

Test run:

```
$ ./search_substrings.sh "6314" input.txt                                                                                
commA6314   ifosfamide               30     12
```

Note that this avoids use of external tools like `grep` which adheres to requirements, although keep in mind this is not a very practical solution, and in real world you'd rather use `Perl` or `awk`